# How properly collect a VARIANT column in snowpark

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowpark dataframe that retrieves a single VARIANT column from a table.
`regions = session.table("REGIONS").select("features")`
How do I take the value of that features column and assign it to a dictionary variable?  `to_dict()` adds `“FEATURES”` as a key, and the json as the value. Not what I want.
I’ve tried: `regions_dict = json.loads(regions.select(F.col("features")))`   That gets the error `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data frame of one column looks like a list. You can extract the rows from the columns as a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary will have the keys and values from the VARIANT column.

```
regions = session.table("REGIONS").select("FEATURES").collect()
regions_dict_list = [json.loads(row.asDict()['FEATURES']) for row in regions]
```